# Chrome app content security policy

Tags: google-chrome-app

**Errors:**

Refused to load the script 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

background.html:9 Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:".

**Solve:**
To resolve this issue, I tried adding

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'
https://www.youtube.com/ https://ssl.google-analytics.com/; object-src 'self'"
```

But then I get the warning:

**'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.**

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't load a script directly from the web. All scripts must be inside the Chrome App's folder. This may require you to download the script and place it into a folder that itself is inside the Chrome App folder.